# Dependency error while installing vlc . Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: dependencies, vlc

In my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS vlc player can't be installed. Actually I'm new to Ubuntu so don't know much about it.
I tried using Software Center but the following error was encountered.

Error was

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 is to be installed
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I tried to install `vlc-nox` from software center but it returns another error regarding `libc6` library.
I checked `libc6` and found that it was already installed.

How can I fix it?

the result after performing command sudo apt install vlc was the following

```
athuls@athuls-desktop:~$ sudo apt install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore7 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
athuls@athuls-desktop:~$
```

Comment: You can try aptitude tool to solve these dependencies for you.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install vlc` from the command line and if you get an error, edit your question to add *everything* that is printed on the terminal.

Comment: fkraiem -- I have edited the question with the new results. Please check it. I  also tried Ubuntu Tweak but no result.

Comment: Sam-- Can you be more specific.?

Comment: You have four packages (`vlc-nox`, `libvlccore7`, `vlc-plugin-notify`, and `vlc-plugin-pulse`) which for some reason cannot be installed. Try installing them with `sudo apt install` and see what you find.

Comment: Try `apt-get update` and then installing `vlc`

Comment: fkraiem : I just did what you said.But it displays same dependency error.

Comment: fkraiem : I just did what you said.But it displays same dependency error. vlc-nox have dependency on libvlc5 so I tried to install libvlc5 . But it shown another dependancy error on libvlccore7.  and i tried to install it, it was depended on vlc-data.  So i finally tried to install vlc-data , but found that vlc-data is already up  to date.   Now i assume removing each and every vlc libraries and performing a clean installation will solve the problem. What you say.? Can you tell me how to unistall all at  once.?  How about removing all multimedia libraries.? What do you think.?

Comment: There is also another problem. I have Synaptic installed. But there is no UI for it. It just running in the background. I reinstalled it. but still no UI. Its running as root . Really something is wrong with this PC. I have graphics and audio problems with this PC.

Comment: God.!! Finally installed vlc .  i tried dpkg--purge command and removed all vlc packages but still there is problem. New trouble is vlc have no UI. I can hear  the audio from background but no UI . Same problem with Synaptic too. No UI. I strongly suspect graphic which is Intel GM45.